# Matplotlib plot graph from Pandas dataframe groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a .txt file named Results.txt which contains a list as below

```
[100.0, 95.42, 97.31, 95.42, 95.17, 95.17, 95.35, 96.24, 95.48]
```

I used the Pandas read_csv function to read the .txt file and make the list into a DataFrame.

```
dd = pd.read_csv('Results.txt')

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ['Results']
df
```

And this is the result

Out[6]:

```
    Results
0    100.00
1     95.42
2     97.31
3     95.42
4     95.17
5     95.17
6     95.35
7     96.24
8     95.48
```

What I know that i need to use groupby function for my DataFrame before plotting a graph for it but it returns me an error.

```
graph = df.groupby('Results').count()
plt.plot(graph)
plt.show()

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Is there anything that i missed or did wrongly before plotting the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.groupby(['result']).size().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have made error in using groupby function. Try this

```
graph = df.groupby(['results'])['results'].count()
graph.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]